# Loop through MFC Child Dialogs, MDIFrames etc

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a way to loop through all MFC Child Dialogs, MDI frames and etc? And is there a way to find out which dialog or window I am looping through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28VS.85%29.aspx) to iterate through child windows of certain window.

Answer (score 7):

Taken from Анатолий Тутов (https://web.archive.org/web/20140110220804/http://www.asis.ru/posts/27):

```
for (CWnd *pWnd = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);  pWnd != NULL;  pWnd = pWnd->GetNextWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT))
{
    //Insert your code here. pWnd is a pointer to control window.
}
```

Comment: It looks like there's a capitalization typo in the code near the end of the line: `pWnd = pwnd->GetNextWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT)` - should be `pWnd->`, not `pwnd->`